# Dockerfile ARG not being properly set in FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I have a typical setup for an image tag but I'm trying to make a multi-stage build:

```
FROM docker.io/library/alpine as first-stage

RUN echo "test"

ARG VERSION="latest"

FROM docker.io/library/hello-world:${VERSION} as second-stage
```

but when I try to build it with a command like:

```
docker build \
    --tag=img-name-dev:latest \
    .
```

(running from the directory that the `Dockerfile` lives in)

I get in my real code:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "link.to.my/image:": invalid reference format
```

or in the minimal reproducible example:

```
Step 4/4 : FROM docker.io/library/hello-world:${VERSION} as second-stage
invalid reference format
```

which indicates to me that the `VERSION` is empty, rather than being filled with `latest`. If I remove the `${VERSION}` and replace it simply with `latest` it works (so it's not a permissions issue pulling the image).

What am I doing wrong?

Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.10
 Git commit:        7155243
 Built:             Thu Jan 19 17:34:12 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.10
  Git commit:       6051f14
  Built:            Thu Jan 19 17:32:03 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.15
  GitCommit:        5b842e528e99d4d4c1686467debf2bd4b88ecd86
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

Docker Compose version v2.13.0
```

Comment: What is the command you are using to build it / what is your _docker-compose.yml_ looking like?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε added more context if that helps

Comment: @BMitch I've created a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `ARG` that is used within a `FROM` command must occur before the first `FROM` statement. So move your `ARG` to the very top of your file -- above the  additional first stage that you mentioned in the comments. See the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).